# AngularJS function continuously calls after page has rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stack-trace

I have a ng-repeat that loops through elements returned from a promise.  Two odd things are happening.  1.  Though I can see the promise returning a single element, I see that one element rendered to HTML but in console I see 4 messages implying the function was called 4 times.  2)  Every 30 seconds or so it looks like the ng-repeat is initializing again as I see the same console.log messages appearing 4 more times every 30 seconds.

```
      <ion-item cache-view="true" class="item-avatar item-icon-right" style="min-height:60px;" ng-repeat="crR in currentR" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/rLater/{{crR.bid}}">
        <div>
          <img id="crR_IconImage" style='margin:0px 8px 0px 0px;float:left;max-width:40px;height:auto;' ng-src="{{crR.fullLogo}}">
          <h3>{{crR.pDate}} @ {{crR.pTime}} (${{crR.quoted}})</h3>
          <p style="padding-top:5px;font-size:12px;">{{crR.vName}}, Status:
            <span>{{getConfName(crR.confirmed)}}</span>
          <i id="customIcon" class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
```

In my HTML view of the app, I do see 1 item listed...however, the `{{getConfName(crR.confirmed)}}` is a function defined as:

```
  $scope.getConfName = function(value) {
    console.log("caller is " + arguments.callee.toString());
    console.log("value: " +value) ;  // <-- this prints 4 times every 30 seconds
    if (value == 0) {
      return "Not Confirmed" ;
    } else if (value == 1) {
      return "Confirmed" ;
    } else if (value == 2) {
      return "Cancelled by Vendor" ;
    } else if (value == 3) {
      return "Cancelled by user" ;
    } else if (value == 4) {
      return "Modified by Vendor" ;
    } else if (value == 5) {
      return "Modified by User" ;
    }
  }
```

In console.log I see `value = 0` printed four times...and then every 30 seconds, `value` is printed four more times.  I tried adding:

```
console.log("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
```

but that errors out as `caller` is undefined.  If I do:

```
console.log("caller is " + arguments.callee.toString());
```

I see the above function printed out to console as such:

```
caller is function (value) {
    console.log("caller is " + arguments.callee.toString());
    console.log("value: " +value) ;
    if (value == 0) {
      return "Not Confirmed" ;
    } else if (value == 1) {
      return "Confirmed" ;
    } else if (value == 2) {
      return "Cancelled by Vendor" ;
    } else if (value == 3) {
      return "Cancelled by user" ;
    } else if (value == 4) {
      return "Modified by Vendor" ;
    } else if (value == 5) {
      return "Modified by User" ;
    }
  }
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why `value = 0` continually prints to console every 30 seconds...and each time it does, it prints it four times.  the only other thing, that I don't feel should be related, is that I have my AdMob ads printing on that app screen every 30 seconds...and the moment the ad changes the console.log `value` messages appear.  Its like the above function is some how being triggered when a new ad is served.  It doesn't make sense to me.